# How to exclude Sonar test classes from test coverage report

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, jacoco, test-coverage

I am using Sonar Qube Version 5.6 with jacoco 0.7.9 and Gradle build to generate sonar test coverage report. But i found my test coverage is showing very low but in eclipse it is high. It is also showing all classes unsed src/test/java/** with zero coverage.
Please tell me how can i exclude all these test classes from output report also tell me how to exclude particular source java package from sonar -jacoco test coverage report. attaching screen shot. [image]

Comment: See the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus)

Comment: Thanks this work for me property "sonar.test.exclusions", "src/test/java/**/*.java"
I am also facing one more issue in AWS code build where my build is failing due to some unknown reason but when i run the build on my local window machine it work fine export report to sonarqube.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
> Unable to blame file src/test/java/com/fmr/common/dal/objectstore/PartyDaoImplTest.java

Comment: how are you running the sonarqube analysis ? which scanner (and which version) are you using ? There seems to be something wrong in your sonarqube project configuration to define what is a test file and what is not.